# imbed time in shell script

Tags: linux

in shell script I need to rename a tb name so that it ends with Y_M_D timestamp, how can this be done?

mysql -u root -ppassword <<EOF
use mydb;
alter table mytb rename to mytb_Y_M_D

EOF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql -u root -ppassword <<EOF
use mydb;
alter table mytb rename to mytb_`date +%y_%m_%d`
EOF
```

Comment: Note that %y is 2-digit year and %Y is 4-digit

Answer (score 0):

The oneliner for that is

```
mysql -u root -password mydb -e "alter table VOTE rename to vote_date_`date +%Y_%m_%d`"
```